# In what sense does "tio" mean "this"? (or does it?)

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Regarding the use of *tio* (and other t-words), these two following sources appear to be in contradiction.

According to PMEG, [p245](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/lokaj/chi.html):

> Simpla TI-vorto ĉiam montras ion ne tute proksiman al la parolanto.
>   TI- vorto + ĉi montras ion proksiman al la parolanto...

While according to Being Colloquial in Esperanto, [10.3](http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq100.html#sec10-3):

> The series in T- (corresponding to English “th” words like “this,”
>   “that,” “there,” “then”) is a general demonstrative, meaning both
>   “this” and “that.”

Hence my question. Is one of these wrong? Or am I misunderstanding something, and these two sources can be reconciled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this question a lot in Duolingo. My advice there, since the responses are checked by computer, is to always use "this" when you see *ĉi tiu* and "that" when it's just *tiu*. In practice, though, the distinction isn't that hard and fast.

**The trouble is not Esperanto. It's English.** The word *ĉi* is used to indicate closeness to the speaker. You really only need it if there's a contrast. If there are two things, the closer one with have *ĉi*.

In English, there's no real difference between pointing at something and asking **"what is this?"** and pointing the same way at the same thing asking **"what is that?"**

This/that is why the Jordan quote doesn't contradict the PMEG quote.

Comment: Interestingly there is no difference in asking "what is this" and "what is that" in Chinese or Japanese as well, without another object to compare the distance. I think I get the point: Jordan meant both these two words would mean the same thing in english, not `tiu` could mean both near and far. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think these two sources are in contradiction. Imagine you're holding an apple in each of your hands and say: *this apple is good but this* [other] *is bad*. Both apples are equally near. In Esperanto, you could say: *tiu pomo estas bona sed ĉi tiu estas malbona*. The second apple with *ĉi tiu* does not imply that it is closer than the first one. In this case it's only a way to make a clear distinction between the two.

*Simpla TI-vorto ĉiam montras ion ne tute proksiman*. How close is something that is not completely close? I think it depends on the context and the intention of the speaker/writer. That's why *this* is not always *ĉi tiu* or *ĉi tio*, but simply *tiu* or *tio*.